# R webscraping from a Drupal views table

Tags: r, drupal, web-scraping

None of the other webscraping solutions seem to work for the task I have of scraping data from a table generated by Drupal views.  While the displayed page source definitely has a table displayed the current code I am attempting to use just returns an empty table instead of a list of 15 rows of displayed tabular information.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, and am novice to intermediate in coding skills with R.  Any help will be much appreciated!

My R code:

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")
projects <- getURL("http://www.mysite.com/projects", userpwd ="username:password")

# parse the document for R representation:
projects.doc <- htmlParse(projects)

# get  the table
projects.tabs <- readHTMLTable(projects.doc, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, I went to this website but there seems to be an error. Could you give an example with an active website?